# Getting coordinates for street path?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am having troubles with getting coordinates for the entire street path. For example, if the street is 1 kilometer long, I would like to get coordinates on every 50 meters. So, it'd be an array of 20 coordinates (latitude and longitude). Is this even possible?
Just to mention, I used `Geocoder` and method `getFromLocationName()` so I am getting only one pair of coordinates for particular street.

Any help would be very much appreciate. It is a dead end for me, can't come up with an idea at all.

Thanks in advance!